# Split data frame into groups and `count` several variables for each group

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm stuck with this presumably easy task.

I have a data set that I want to group by on a certain variable and then for each of these groups, I want to get the count for several vars. I think that's a job for `map`, but I can't get my head around how that should look like. My idea was sth. like:

```
library(tidyverse)

count_vars <- c("vs", "am", "gear")

mtcars |>
  group_split(cyl) |>
  map2(.x = _,
       .y = !!!count_vars,
       .f = ~.x |>
         count(.y))
```

But this apparently doesn't work.

The expected outcome would be a list with one element per group and within each of these elements I would have another set of lists (one for each count var). I'd also be fine in getting a data frame within each group where the counts for each var are just row binded.

Any ideas?

Note: I do not want to have nested counts like in a simple `count(as, vs, gear)` command, instead I want to have three different "tables", one for each variable.

An example (doing it only for two vars could look like:

```
[[1]][1]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     vs     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0     1
2     1    10

[[1]][2]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     am     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0     3
2     1     8

[[2]][1]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     vs     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0     3
2     1     4

[[2]][2]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     am     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0     4
2     1     3

[[3]][1]
# A tibble: 1 × 2
     vs     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0    14

[[3]][2]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     am     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0    12
2     1     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `group_split`, loop over the `list`, `select` only the columns from the 'count_vars', then loop over the columns, create a `tibble` from the columns (as `count` expects a data.frame/tibble) and get the `count` - results in a nested list of tibbles i.e. for each 'cyl' split list, there would be 3 tibbles

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mtcars |> 
  group_split(cyl) |> 
  map(.x = _, ~ .x |> 
       select(all_of(count_vars)) |> 
       imap(~ tibble(!!.y := .x) |> 
     count(across(everything()))))
```

-output

```
[1]]
[[1]]$vs
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     vs     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0     1
2     1    10

[[1]]$am
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     am     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0     3
2     1     8

[[1]]$gear
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   gear     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     3     1
2     4     8
3     5     2


[[2]]
[[2]]$vs
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     vs     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0     3
2     1     4

[[2]]$am
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     am     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0     4
2     1     3

[[2]]$gear
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   gear     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     3     2
2     4     4
3     5     1


[[3]]
[[3]]$vs
# A tibble: 1 × 2
     vs     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0    14

[[3]]$am
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     am     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0    12
2     1     2

[[3]]$gear
# A tibble: 2 × 2
   gear     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     3    12
2     5     2
```

---

Or another option is to use `nest` and store it in a single data as `list` column

```
out <-  mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl, all_of(count_vars)) %>%
  nest(data = all_of(count_vars)) %>%
  mutate(data =  map(data, ~ .x %>% 
       split.default(names(.x)) %>%
        map(~ .x %>%
       count(across(everything())))))
```

-output

```
> out
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl data            
  <dbl> <list>          
1     6 <named list [3]>
2     4 <named list [3]>
3     8 <named list [3]>
> out$data[[1]]
$am
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     am     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0     4
2     1     3

$gear
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   gear     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     3     2
2     4     4
3     5     1

$vs
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     vs     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0     3
2     1     4
```

Comment: But this gives me just one set of counts, but I'd need counts for all three vars for each group of cyl, so there should be three sets of counts.

Comment: And the alternative gives me the nested counts, which is not what I need. So `cyl` has three groups, and for each of these groups I need three independent tables, one for am, one for vs, one for gear.

Comment: Looks like my question wasn't as straightforward as I thought, so thanks a lot for getting a solution anyway. I ended up using your nesting approach (I always forget this one as an option to reshape and operate on data).

Answer (score 0):

Does this dplyr approach produce the output you're looking for?

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  count(vs, am, gear)
```

If not, can you please show an example of what you hope to see?

*Edit:*

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  add_tally(vs, name = 'vs') %>%
  add_tally(am, name = 'am') %>%
  add_tally(gear, name = 'gear') %>%
  select(cyl, vs, am, gear) %>%
  distinct()
```

Comment: No, because here we get a nested cound of vs, am, gear. However, I want the results for counting vs, then I want to get the counts for am, then for gear, i.e. the vars are independent from each other.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not following what you expect the output to look like. Please see if the new code in my edited post is closer.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. However, you manually specify the vars to be counted which is unfeasible in my real life case (where I have many more), hence I need a programmatic approach where I loop through a vector of vars (without necessary using a for loop).